# ConvertTo-HTML outputs System.Object[] from PSObject

Tags: html, powershell

I try to convert a PSObject to a HTML table and get `System.Object[]` as output.

```
$Result = New-Object PSObject

foreach ($Location in $Locations) {
    $Servers = GetServers -Location $Location
    $Value = @()

    foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
        if (Test-Path Path) {
            $value += $Server #Background of td should be green
        } else {
            $Value += $Server #Background of td should be red
        }
    }

    $Result | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $Location -Value $Value
}

$Result ConvertTo-Html
```

Without converting to HTML the output is:

```
Location1  : {Server1, Server2}
Location2  : {Server3, Server4}
Location3  : {Server5, Server6}
```

Trying to convert:

```
<td>System.Object[]</td>
```

And I'd like to have a table like:

```
Location1     Location2     Location3
---------     ---------     ---------                                                                 
Server1       Server3       Server5
Server2       Server4       Server6
```

If it's possible I would like to have different `<td>` background (as commented in the script).

Comment: `-Value ($Value -join ', ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConvertTo-Html` doesn't know how to format string arrays, so you'll have to convert the value to a string before passing it to the cmdlet:

```
$Result | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $Location -Value ($Value -join ', ')
```

Comment: Thank You! Saw your answers with -join ',' from other threads but I failed :3 . Is it possible to "manipulate" the <td> in advance? I have an IF-Statement to difference between exists and not exists. Is it possible at this point of code to manipulate the following <td> output (background color) after convertto-html?

Comment: No, that's not possible with `ConvertTo-HTML`, but you may want to have a look at [`PSHTML`](https://pshtml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)